# How to disable iOS HTML5 video controls?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios

I have a site with a background video playing. In desktop and android when I click in video nothing happens, but when I'm on iOs it goes full screen, come to front of screen and show video controls. Is there a way to avoid this? I've already tried using an invisible div with z-index greater and width/height = 100%, it did not worked.

Comment: Please put your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work but I'm not sure. Also, What IOS version are you using? since IOS12 handles videos differently than other versions do. code: `<video src='xxxx' muted className='landing__empty-video' loop playsInline autoPlay={false} controls={false} preload='auto' type='video/mp4' />`

Comment: playsInline did the trick, thank you very much